# How can I prove that expectation of conditional random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I know the following results are true.
However, I forgot to prove them. Please let me know how to prove them.

$$E(X)=E(E(X|Y))\tag1$$
$$P(X)=E(P(X|Y))\tag2$$

---

(1)

\begin{align}
E(E(X|Y))&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}E(X|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dxf_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dxf_Y(y)dy\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy\\
&=E(X)
\end{align}

Comment: The first equality follows directly from the definition of $E(X\mid Y)$. What do you mean with $P(X)$ and $P(X\mid Y)$?

Comment: Here, $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, and $P$ is probability.

Comment: Yes, but what is $P(X)$?

Comment: I do not know how to explain it, I will just give you an example. If $X\sim{}Exponential(\lambda)$, then $f_X(x)=\lambda{}\exp(-\lambda{}x)$ and $E(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Comment: Isn't that $EX$, i.e. the expectation of $X$?

Comment: @Danny_Kim What do you mean by "$P$" is probability"? $P$ is usually probability measure defined on some $\sigma$-algebra of measurable set, but random variable $X$ is not a member of this $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in conditional probability $P(X \in A \mid Y)=E(1_{X^{-1}(A)} \mid Y)$

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are saying. TT Just my textbook used those two equations frequenty. Although I've already memorized them, I want to know why it is.

Comment: Do you have the textbook at hand? Do you know the definition of $E(X|Y)$?

Comment: The second is a form of [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Applications), I think you can obtain if from the law of total expectation $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]]$ by taking $X = 1_{A}$.

Comment: In order to notice what I want to ask, I copied the prove of (1) equation even though I do not understand with 100%.

Comment: How are you *defining* $E(X|Y)$? The definition which is familiar to probabilists is rooted in measure theory, specifically in the Radon-Nikodym theorem. In that definition, $E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$ is built into the definition of $E(X|Y)$. But there are more restricted ways of defining it which only apply to certain types of distributions (e.g. discrete distributions), and you are probably using one of those since you have said you don't know measure theory.

Comment: (Cont.) In the discrete case everything is simple, it falls out of the definition of conditional probability. In the continuous case there are some concerns about division by zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, I do not like the proof of (1) as I don't remember that existence of densities is necessary. Lets begin with $\sigma$-algebras, just using the fact that for random variable $Y$ by definition $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]= \mathbb{E}\mathbb[X|\sigma(Y)]$.

I will take the following definition of conditional expectation with respect to sigma-algebra:

Conditional expectation of random variable $\xi$ with respect to sub-sigma-algebra $\mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{F}$ is a random variable $\zeta = \mathbb{E}[\xi|\mathbb{C}]$ that follows two conditions:

(a) $\zeta$ is measurable with respect to $\mathbb{C}$

(b) $\mathbb{E}[\xi 1_A] = \mathbb{E}[\zeta 1_A] $ for any $A \in \mathbb{C}$.

Now we actually want to prove "law of total expectation" that

$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\xi|\mathbb{C} ]]=\mathbb{E}[\xi]$

This is true, because we can set $A = \Omega$ in (b) and get rid of such an indicator.

In our case, as both $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb{F}$-measurabe, $\mathbb{C}= \sigma(Y) \subset \mathbb{F}$.

The second equality

$P(A) = \mathbb{E}[P(A|\mathbb{C})], \ A \in \mathbb{F} $

is a form of [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Applications). I can't see any problems just to derive it from the law of total expectation by setting $\xi = 1_A$ for any $A \in \mathbb{F}$, then corresponding expectations will turn into probabilities by definition.

---

Please, correct me if I'm wrong, because I don't understand why to limit yourself to densities when everything just comes from the basic definitions.

---

Edit2: Ok, lets try to prove the second using conditional densities, but I'm not good with this part, e.g. I don't know what is defined and what we should prove.

As far as I understand, looking on the proof of (1), they should think of $\mathbb{E}[P(X|Y)]$ as

$$\mathbb{E}[P(Y|X)] = \int_{R} P(Y|X=x)f_X(x)dx$$

Then we can use the proof from [the book](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=CDLfI5pgjkAC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=continuous++law+of+total+probability++proof&source=bl&ots=HFNccjaAxD&sig=bBzaKkCMnshOe97M9yMFj3cU6-4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5pbCFzN7MAhXLBSwKHVZ7BPgQ6AEIUTAJ#v=onepage&q=continuous%20%20law%20of%20total%20probability%20%20proof&f=false)

\begin{align} P(Y \in B) &= \int_B f_Y(y) dy \\&= \int_B \int_R f_Y(y|x)f_X(x)dxdy \\&= \int_R \int_B f_Y(y|x)f_X(x)dydx \\&=\int_{R} P(Y\in B|X=x)f_X(x)dx \end{align}

which is desired.

Comment: Actually, I am not majoring mathematics. I've taken a probability class for engineering students. So, I am not used to using sigma algebra and measure. (I am now learning Lebesgue Measure.) I think you proved very advanced and nice (although I don't know it is correct or not). I hope to prove them without using measure theory.

Comment: @Danny_Kim I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Statement 1 follows from the definition of $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$:

A version of $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ is a variable $Z$ such that $Z$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable and $\mathbb{E}(X1_A)=\mathbb{E}(Z1_A)$ for all $A\in\sigma(Y)$.

It is trivial that $\Omega\in\sigma (Y)$ (where $\Omega$ is the sample space), hence $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X1_\Omega)=\mathbb{E}(Z1_\Omega)=\mathbb{E}(Z)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|Y)).$$

The meaning of Statement 2 is not clear to me, I doubt that it is well-defined.