# Questions about the distribution of $Y$ given the distributions of $X$ and of $Y$ conditionally on $X$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> $\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$Given: $X$ uniform on $(0,1)$ and $Y\mid X=x$ with distribution $N(x,1)$.
>
> Question 1: Determine $\E(Y^2)$ and $\Var (Y)$.

Answer 1: 
$$ \Var(Y)= \E[\Var (Y \mid X)] + \Var[\E(Y\mid X)] = 1 + \Var(X) = 13/12$$

$$\Var(Y) = \E(Y^2) - [\E(Y)]^2 $$

Rewrite this into $$\E(Y^2) = \Var (Y) + (\E[\E(Y\mid X)])^2 = 4/3$$

> Question 2: Show  $P[Y \le 1] = \int^1_0 \Phi(1-x)\,dx $ with $\Phi$ as standard normal cdf.

Answer 2: $$P(Y \le 1 \mid X) = P(Y-x \le 1-x \mid X=x) = \Phi(1-x). $$ Then we take the expectation to get the probability we are looking for: $$P[Y \le 1] = E[P(Y \le 1 \mid X)] = \int^1_0 \Phi(1-x)f_X(x)\,x = \int^1_0 \Phi(1-x)\,dx$$ So that we get the desired result.

I'm asking whether the answer to question 1 is right and for a little bit of help for the second one.

EDIT: Just saw $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y\mid X}(x,y)$.

EDIT2: Thanks for the help guys really appreciate it!

Comment: Answer 1 is correct. Re Question 2, you may start by computing $P(Y\leqslant1\mid X=x)$ for every $x$.

Comment: "EDIT: Just saw $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(x,y)$ " Certainly not!

Comment: But $f_x(x) = 1$ right?

Comment: Yes, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)$ and, if $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}$.

Comment: Yea that statement was not meant in general only for this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first is correct (law of total variance), for the second I suggest [law of total probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787390/) $P(Y) =E[P(Y\mid X)]$:

$$P(Y\leq 1) = E[P(Y \leq 1\mid X)] = \int_{X} P(Y \leq 1 \mid x)\cdot  f(x) dx$$

$Y\mid X = U \sim N(x,1). \ $, We know that $U <c, U \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) \Leftrightarrow Z<\frac{c-\mu}{\sigma}$, where $Z \sim N(0,1)$. So:

$$P(Y \leq 1 \mid x) = (P(U\leq 1), \ U \sim N(x,1)\ )  = \Phi(\frac{1-x}{1}) $$

and we have what we needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I figured it out now.